# My Xcode's code sense is not working? How to solve?

Tags: xcode

I try to restart my mac, restart Xcode, delete the folder  where ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and XCode -> Window -> Project -> Delete, but also don't have effect. What should I do?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: What is code sense? You mean autocomplete?

Comment: Input the letter begin of the method, Xcode can not give me any prompt of the method...

Comment: I only wait for it, when I try to use again, it's working and give me prompt. thanks.